# How to get the success delivery count from FCM by Topic using message id

Tags: angular, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the application we are  already sending the notification using device token. In this we are getting the response of success and failure count. Now we have a new requirement to change from **Device token to Topic**. When i check the response, we are only getting the message id.

**Is there any way to get the success and failure count from FCM by topic?**